# In Install4J is it possible to update the sys.preferredJRE variable?

Tags: install4j

I have an installer whose purpose is updating the max version of a JDK for an existing installation (we require JDK, not JRE), and pointing the existing installation to run with the later version of the JDK (which is user pre-installed and user-specified).

In the installer, I have code that calls JVM.setPreferredJVM() from a directory chooser form component. According to [the API](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/) for JVMSelector, it says this method will "Set the preferred JRE/JDK for your application." According to the [help docs](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/index.html) on variables (sys.preferredJRE), "This variable will only be set after the "Install files" action has run."

When I run the installer, I see that the setPreferredJVM() method is called, but the sys.preferredJRE is not set to what I wanted, it still references the old JVM. This is a problem because my subsequent "Add VM Options" steps use the sys.preferredJRE variable.

I expected that calling JVMSelector.setPreferredJVM() would update sys.preferredJRE, but it does not. How can I accomplish this so that the user can set the preferred JVM/JDK during the install?

Comment: Inside the code, I put the JDK that I want inside a custom variable called jdkPath. Then *after* the install files step, I put in a set variable action, with script of context.getVariable("jdkPath") and variable name sys.preferredJre. This does update sys.preferredJre. Still confused as to what the JVM.setPreferredJVM() method is actually doing though. Does it do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, it will be fixed in 6.0.2. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get an interim build with the fix.

Comment: Can do, thanks! I also saw that pref_jre.cfg was not being updated with the user-selected JDK, and was going to try to work around it with a "Modify text files" action. Do you expect that this bug fix will also modify pref_jre.cfg, or should I continue working on this action?

Comment: pref_jre.cfg should be updated if you call JVMSelector.setPreferredJVM() after the "Install files" action has run